# Pagination Error - Same Posts Displaying Over Again

Tags: pagination

```
             <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php query_posts('offset=1'); ?>
                        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                         <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                             <div class="col-sm-6">
                                 <a class="post-link" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                 <div class="post">
                                     <div class="post-image">
                                      <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                             </div>
                                 <div class="post-title">
                                     <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                                <div class="post-excerpt">
                                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?><p>
                                </div>
                                 </div>
                                 </div>
                            </a>
                             </div>
                         <?php endwhile; ?>
                         <div class="post-nav">
               <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older Posts' ); ?></div>
               <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer Posts' ); ?></div>
             </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <?php get_template_part("template-parts/sidebar"); ?>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php query_posts('offset=1'); ?>
```

This is your problem. The pagination functions work off of the main query, but you replace the main query at the start of every page, and the only thing you've told it is that the offset is 1, how is it supposed to know you wanted page 2?!

So instead, I'm going to suggest a significantly improved way to do this. One that doesn't double the number of database queries, pollute the main query, and is significantly faster:

The `pre_get_posts` filter.

`query_posts` does not modify the posts WP retrieves, WP still goes and fetches them. The function replaces the query, so lets modify the original query instead to fetch what we wanted, e.g.

```
function add_offset_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'offset', '1' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_offset_to_query' );
```

Keep in mind though that pagination relies on the `offset` parameter, so this query will never truly work with pagination.

You also need to put this in `functions.php`. WP uses the query to decide which template to load, so by the time the template is loaded the query has already ran.

A good rule of thumb is:

- Never use `query_posts`, pretend it doesn't exist, there is no valid use, it brings only pain and headaches
- If you need to change which posts WP fetches, use `pre_get_posts`
- If you need to fetch some posts for a sub-section of a page, use a `WP_Query` loop
- `get_posts`, `get_pages`, etc etc all use `WP_Query`, save some time and cut out the middle man, instead of learning lots of alternatives with weird quirks